# ASP.NET Web API 2 operation DELETE with guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple method:

```
    public async Task<string> Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var success = await ProductFacade.DeleteProductAsync(id);
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return $"Deleted product with id: {id}";
    }
```

But when I try to make a DELETE request with Fiddler, it says:

> {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] Delete(System.Guid)' in 'DemoEshop.WebApi.Controllers.ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

DELETE Request is: http://localhost:56118/api/Products/aa16dc64-5c07-40fe-a916-175165b9b90

Really interesting is that my Put method also uses Guid as parameter but works. Here it is:

```
    public async Task<string> Put(Guid id, [FromBody]ProductDto product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var success = await ProductFacade.EditProductAsync(product);
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return $"Updated product with id: {id}";
    }
```

Do you have any idea why DELETE does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GUID that you are sending via Fiddler contains 31 hex digit instead of 32.

http://localhost:56118/api/Products/aa16dc64-5c07-40fe-a916-175165b9b90

The last fifth segment should have 12 hex digits, but you have 11. This will cause the `Guid.Parse()` to fail.

Comment: Thank you very much,the fifth segment should be 175165b9b90f, the last digit somehow ran away.